# Nav Menu Item Flexi Width

Tags: css, nav

I'd like to do a nav menu like Zillow.com where as the screen shrinks, the width of each item shrinks a bit also. How is this done?

Here is the [page](https://ifindproperty.sslsvc.com/new-site-test/home/) I'm working on.

Cheers

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Noted. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as inspected from the css of Zillow.com, you can find these attribute on the menu item `<section class="nav-section nav-dropdown nav-section_wide" > ... </section>`

the css part is:

```
.nav-top-container .nav-section {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp, the `flex` attribute `Let all the flexible items be the same length, regardles of its content`. And the menu section's parent `div` has css:

```
max-width: 680px;
-webkit-flex-grow: 10;
-ms-flex-grow: 10;
-webkit-box-flex: 10;
-ms-flex-positive: 10;
flex-grow: 10;
```

so it has max width 680px, but will change width when screen gets smaller by 10. Please refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp